# Aurora connection from a EC2 in another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

My EC2 instance is in Asia Pacific (Sydney), and I have an Aurora Mysql in US East (N. Virginia).

I tried to make the VPC peering connection, set the route tables in both VPC Route tables (EC2 and Aurora) and EC2 won't connect to Aurora

Am I forgetting something? I read several pages from AWS and I couldn't find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: You could test your VPC Peering configuration by launching an Amazon EC2 instance in the same VPC as Aurora, then try connecting between the two EC2 instances. This will help you identify whether it is a networking issue or a database connectivity issue. When you say "EC2 won't connect", do you get an error message? Does it fail immediately, or does it take some time to fail? (If it takes some time, then it is likely to be a networking issue. If it fails immediately, then it is a permissions issue.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein hey john, I did and it works fine.... the problem only happens on two different regions

Comment: You currently have an EC2 instance in Sydney and Aurora in N.Virginia. My suggestion was to launch an EC2 instance in N.Virginia, then try to connect from one EC2 instance (eg in Sydney) to the other EC2 instance (eg in N.Virginia). This will test the VPC Peering connection without involving Aurora. That way, it is using two different regions.